# ¿Cómo partir una tabla en dos subtablas al azar con el mismo número de filas?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando realizar esta consigna con la tabla "iris" pero no estoy entendiendo bien como ordenar los términos.

Alguna ayuda gentil por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero haber entendido la pregunta, y quizás puedes intentar es lo siguiente:

```
# Definir el número de dataframes que quieres:
n <- 2

# Split el dataframe en dos y guardar el resultado como una lista de objetos:
df1 <- split(iris, factor(sort(rank(row.names(iris))%%n)))

# Examinar el objeto:
df1 %>% str()

List of 2
 $ 0:'data.frame':  75 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:75] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:75] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:75] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:75] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
  ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ 1:'data.frame':  75 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:75] 6.6 6.8 6.7 6 5.7 5.5 5.5 5.8 6 5.4 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:75] 3 2.8 3 2.9 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.7 2.7 3 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:75] 4.4 4.8 5 4.5 3.5 3.8 3.7 3.9 5.1 4.5 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:75] 1.4 1.4 1.7 1.5 1 1.1 1 1.2 1.6 1.5 ...
  ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```